# how can i make a rails method to generate form by passing form's labels as parameters into the method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi all i am new in ruby on rails and i am making a form using simple form gem. Now i want to simplify it more and try to make a method that takes labels as parameters and then can generate a simple form.
eg.
instead of

```
<%= u.input :name, required: true %>
<%= u.input :email, required: true %>
<%= u.input :phone %>
```

i want to call a method with parameters

```
(name,email,phone)
```

to generate the form.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a helper method like so:

```
Module ApplicationHelper
  def build_me_a_form(path, fields) # pass fields as an array ['Name', 'Email', 'Phone']
    page_content = ''

    unless fields.blank?
      page_content = form_tag(path)
      fields.each do |field|
        page_content += text_field_tag(field.downcase.to_sym)
      end

      page_content += submit_tag
    end

    page_content
  end
end

# View
<%= build_me_a_form(some_path, ['name', 'Email', 'Phone']) %>
```

That should get you started at least, you can extend this to accept a hash of field name and type for example, you may also want to have an alternate version that accepts an object and builds a `form_for(object)` instead of tags, or generate labels...